# How to get ALL content of a few XML tags including children tags and content in Java

Tags: java, xml-parsing

In Java I know a number of different XML parsers, like DOM, S(t)AX and variants. I used them many times, so recognizing and reading the contents of one tag is simple.

**How can I read *ALL* (nested) content between a starter tag and it's closing tag?** In between can be a number of other tags.

**XLST will not do the trick** when there is a mandatory sequence between them, e.g. first get tag1 (and all content) and then tag2. This will be repeated a number of times till the complete XML file is scanned.

The content will include other tags. That content should NOT be parsed as seperate tags or content.

The purpose is to find say 3 special tags while scanning the file.

I looked at **similar questions** without any result. I programmed it via String processing (indexOf, etc), but that may not the most elegant solution.

Suppose I have this XML file:

```
<parent
  <level1>
    <level2a>
      **** i need all content from this line
      <p>... etc ... </p>
      to this line ****
    </level2a>
  </level1>
  <level2b class="d">
    **** and all content from this line
    content of 2b possibly with child / other tags
    to this line *****
  </level2b>
  <level2b other="e">
    this content is not useful
  </level2b>
  ...
</parent>
```

Suppose I need all content, so including any child tags and content, of '<level2a>' **and** '<level2b class="d">'. How can I get this done in Java?

The result would be:

```
**** i need all content from this line
<p>... etc ... </p>
to this line ****
```

And

```
**** and all content from this line
content of 2b possibly with child / other tags
to this line *****
```

Comment: Consider using XSLT.

Comment: Thanks for answering. XLST will in this case not do the trick because I need to know the order of the tags. Checking them after each other does not reveal the order of the tags.

Comment: It has been quite a while, but would the "attribute" axis not preserve order?

Comment: Thank you for helping. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no standard solution for this. So, scanning groups of tags with keeping the order in which they occur. Keeping the order means that I cannot work with XSLT and similars.

Finally created my general purpose solution with Sax.

If you find a better solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

did not know before that getElementsByTagName("*") does that,

`

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(file);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    System.out.println("Root element " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

    NodeList nodeList=doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (int i=0; i<nodeList.getLength(); i++) 
    {
        // Get element
        Element element = (Element)nodeList.item(i);
        System.out.println(element.getNodeName());
    }
```

`

Comment: This solution does not answer my question. After finding an element, you still have to access all seperate content parts of the main element.